# jquery.layout-latest.js overflow alsways visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

With jquery.layout-latest.js I created a layout. I tried with CSS and JavaScript to set the overflow to be hidden.

But I always get style = ..overflow: auto;.... for

```
<div class="ui-layout-north ui-layout-pane ui-layout-pane-north"
```

for the other panes overflow is set to hidden , how would I properly set overflow: hidden for ui-layout-north ?

Comment: Please show some of the code being used - ideally a JSFiddle or something.

Comment: all css files does have only overflow: hidden entries. Howerver there is this  $C.css( _c.content.cssDemo ); // add padding & overflow: auto to content-div in jquery-layout-latest-js so I think Marcos has been right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must to share CSS but I think that is an override problem. Try to apply this:

```
 .ui-layout-north {
         overflow: hidden !important;
 }
```